# Compose Excel/Grid View: Horizontal Scroll Issue When Dynamically Adding Values to Row for all the columns"

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on a Compose-based project where I'm trying to create an Excel/Grid-like view. This view dynamically adds values to both the front and end of all columns, similar to an Electronic Program Guide (EPG).

```
    LazyColumn(state = scrollLazyState, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    stickyHeader {
        Row {
            if (channelList.isNotEmpty()) {
                StaticImage(coroutineScope, resetToNow, scrollState, scrollLazyState)
            }
            Box(modifier = Modifier.horizontalScroll(scrollState)) {
                LazyRow(
                    modifier = modifier,
                    userScrollEnabled = false,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(EpgUtil.margin / 2)
                ) {

                    items(timeList.size) {
                        TimeView(
                            timeInfo = timeList[it],
                            modifier = EpgUtil.rowHeightModifier
                                .width(cellWidthInt.dp)
                                .border(width = .5.dp, color = Black)

                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    items(count = channelList.size) { rowIndex ->
        val channelData = channelList[rowIndex]
        Row {
            ChannelView(
                epgChannel = channelData,
                modifier = EpgUtil.programRowModifier.combinedClickable(
                    onClick = { onChannelClick(channelData) },
                    onLongClick = { onChannelLongClick(channelData) }
                )
            )
            val programsList = programsMap?.get(channelData.channelId)
            if (programsList != null) {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.horizontalScroll(scrollState)) {
                    LazyRow(
                        modifier = modifier.padding(start = EpgUtil.margin / 2),
                        userScrollEnabled = false,
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(EpgUtil.margin / 2)
                    ) {
                        items(programsList.size) {
                            val program = programsList[it]
                            ProgramRow(
                                epgProgram = program,
                                cellWidth = cellWidthInt.dp,
                                modifier = EpgUtil.programRowModifier.combinedClickable(
                                    onClick = {
                                        onProgramClick(program, channelData)
                                    },
                                    onLongClick = {
                                        onProgramLongClicked(program, channelData)
                                    }
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am also manually handling the scroll since I need to scroll all the lazy rows together

```
LaunchedEffect(scrollState, timeList.firstOrNull()?.timeMills, timeList.indices, showLoading) {
    val oneCellWidth = calculateOneCellWidth() // Assume it's constant
    snapshotFlow { scrollState.value }.collect { _ ->
        scrollStateMaxValue = scrollState.maxValue
        if (canScrollAutomaticallyState.value && scrollStateMaxValue != 0 && !showLoading) {
            if (scrollState.value == scrollStateMaxValue) {

                reachedEndOfScroll()
                canScrollAutomaticallyState.value = false
                shouldResetLayout = true
            } else if (scrollState.value == 0) {

                reachedStartOfScroll()
                canScrollAutomaticallyState.value = false
            }
        }
        val newVisibleItemIndex = scrollState.value / oneCellWidth
        if (newVisibleItemIndex in timeList.indices) {
            val newLastScrollTimeMills = timeList[newVisibleItemIndex].timeMills
            if (lastScrollTimeMills != newLastScrollTimeMills) {
                lastScrollTimeMills = newLastScrollTimeMills
                canScrollAutomaticallyState.value = true
            }
            updateHeaderOnScroll(lastScrollTimeMills)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using LazyRow within LazyColumn, and I manually calculate the width for each LazyRow, which I then pass as a modifier. While I understand that this approach may impact recycling efficiency, I haven't found a better alternative to achieve the desired functionality.

I am open to suggestions and recommendations